# Cover image now showing (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a [site for my son](http://leggacysoccer.com/) using Bootstrap and added custom.css. I tried using an image as background cover but it's not showing up. How can I fix this? 
[This is custom.css](http://leggacysoccer.com/css/custom.css)

```css
body {
 color: #036;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 2rem; 
  background: url(images/field-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.container {
background-color: #fff;
width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
background: url(images/field-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

With

```
background: url(../images/field-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

The path to your image in the css is wrong. If you add ../ before images then it works (this means going up one level). More about css paths here, which is very useful: https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

By the way, you don't need the vendor prefixes for background-size. You can check if you need to prefix here: http://shouldiprefix.com/